# Main structure for a MVVM WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

In one hand I have my model which had to collect data from several files and build a oriented object database, and in another I have my interface in which I want to display data from my database . So I use binding but my ComboBox, etc.. remain empty. I have the feeling that my database is built then erased when the interface is launched. Here's the code of my Main defined in the App.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    [STAThread]
    public static void Main()
    {
        var application = new App();
        application.InitializeComponent();
        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo("P:\\....");
        Model model = new Model(dir);
        model.entityBox.initialize();
        application.Run();
    }
}
```

Code for binding in MainWindow.xaml:

```
  <Window.DataContext>
    <local:EntityBox></local:EntityBox>
  </Window.DataContext>
  <Grid>
    <ComboBox x:Name="critereComboBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Criteres}"/>
```

In EntityBox.cs:

```
        private List<string> _criteres = new List<string>();
        public void initialize()
        {
            _criteres.Add("TXC");
            _criteres.Add("TYC");
            _criteres.Add("TZC");
            _criteres.Add("MXC");
            _criteres.Add("MYC");
            _criteres.Add("MZC");
        }
        public List<string> Criteres
        {
            get{ return _criteres; }
        }
```

Comment: what is the problem? and what did you expect the code to achieve？

Comment: I expect that after building my database the interface could pick up some data in it and display it. But when I try to bind a ComboBox for example to one of my project's class property it remains empty

Comment: Then post the codes that you tried to bind the ComboBox.

Comment: Ok it's done, tell me if you need something more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize combobox inside context class, because when you use XAML to bind your data context, the context class is created independently by XAML, the model creation in `Main` function has literally no effect to your Control.
You also need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` to your Model (ViewModel?) class. I am also suggest you to step into MVVM approach.

Comment: Okaie I understand, thank you for you response. I created my model in the MainWindow.xaml.cs and it works well!

Comment: @NicolasPeuzin that's not very great. You can just change the method for setting the dataContext to Window. Instead of inner setting in xaml do it "outside" where you create your `Window`.

Comment: you suggest that I set the dataContext of my mainWindow in my main?(App.xaml.cs)

Comment: @Asw If you stick to List, I think it should be `INotifyCollectionChanged ` instead?

Comment: I will suggest to use `ObservableCollection<T>` instead of `List<T>` and implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` for each property of `T`

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it's a one-way binding. A short answer is to use `ObservableCollection`

`private ObservableCollection<string> _criteres = new ObservableCollection<string>();`

As it will notify when you call Add, but you might need to call them in UIDispatcher.

Comment: Thank you. Can I have a two-way binding with a List ?

Comment: You can, declear `ItemsSource="{Binding Stations,Mode=TwoWay}"` and implement `INotifyPropertyChanged `. But genrally you don't need TwoWay binding for ComboBox as user won't be able to change the item by default. Howerver it is possible if you have a self-made DataTemplate for Item.

Comment: You are right. To get user's selection I can just use ComboBox.SelectedItemProperty

Comment: And you should try update your `List` after initializing ,you will see what I mean. The UI won't change unless you bind `List` again.